# Concatenating all list values to an array in python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, concatenation

I would like to concatenate all numpy arrays (all same size) in a python dict to a new array.

```
dict = {'some_key_1':np.array([1,2,3,4]), 'some_key_2':np.array([2,3,4,5]), ...}
```

the result that I would like to see is:

```
result = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]])
```

whats the best way to do that?

Edit: Solution seems to be slightly different for python 2 and 3. The accepted answer solves it for python 3.

Comment: How about `np.array(dict.values())`? If you have a ragged number of elems that could be an issue.

Comment: result is an object that I can't work with, not an array unortunately: array(dict_values([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]]))

Comment: I have posted a python-version independent solution utilizing `vstack`, have a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, you'd need to convert the `dict.values()` to a list first.

> The objects returned by dict.keys(), dict.values() and dict.items()
>   are view objects. They provide a dynamic view on the dictionary’s
>   entries, which means that when the dictionary changes, the view
>   reflects these changes.
>   (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping)

```
import numpy as np
data = {'some_key_1':np.array([1,2,3,4]), 'some_key_2':np.array([2,3,4,5])}
print(np.array(list(data.values())))
# [[1 2 3 4]
# [2 3 4 5]]
```

You get a 2-D array, with rows in a random order (Python `dict`s are unordered).

To get a 1-D array, you can use [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
print(np.concatenate(list(data.values())))
# [1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5]
```

If the order is important, you could use a list of tuple or an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of a `dict`.

Comment: Thank's thats it! I use python 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way:

```
result = np.array(list(dict.values()))
```

With `list`, the dictionary's values will be stored in a list (i.e. one obtains a list where each item is a numpy array). This list of numpy arrays can then itself be converted to a numpy array by applying `np.array()`.

You should not use `dict` as a name for your dictionary, though, as this shadows the built-in name [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict). Instead, use e.g.:

```
result = np.array(list(dct.values()))
```

And make sure to rename your dictionary to `dct`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all values of a dictionary by using dictionary.values() and pass it to numpy.array

```
import numpy as np
np.array(list(dict.values()))
```

Please do not use dict as name it is a reserved keyword in python

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
data = {'some_key_1':np.array([1,2,3,4]), 'some_key_2':np.array([2,3,4,5])}
np.array(list(data.values()))
```

**Output**

```
array([[2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```